# Access custom attributes for AWS Cognito User

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to get a custom attribute for a user in Cognito. In the AWS console I can see the custom attribute is set but in iOS when I make the call to `AWSCognitoIdentityUser.getDetails().continueOnSuccessWith(block:)` the response does not contain the custom attributes. Why would this be and how can I get access to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how we accessed all attributed for cognito user.

```
//var params = {                                                                                                           
//  AccessToken: 'STRING_VALUE'                                                                                            
//};

cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getUser(params, function(err, data) {                                             
        if (err) {                                                                                                         
            callback(null, err);                                                                                           
        } else {                                                                                                           
            callback(null, data);                                                                                          
        }                                                                                                                  
});
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT1:**

Also you need to ensure the custom attributes are with read permissions.
If you don't have read permissions, it will not be returned in your request.

Comment: AWS maintains the consistency with their signature regardless of which SDK you use. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/3c855bdc540d55a7c6af8b08d69d8af251079db5/AWSCognitoIdentityProvider/AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.m . reference here.

Comment: Oh right! Sorry. Can I ask where you get the access token?

Comment: Once you login, you will have the accessToken in response.

Comment: Ok so I'm getting the same result going that route. My custom attribute is not present in the response. All other attributes are however

Comment: Problem is not with your call, you need to enable read permissions on your custom attributes for your api call to return.

Comment: Awesome! The permissions were the problem. If you can update your answer I can mark it solved

Comment: I did update the answer with the permission issue. Not sure where you missed it. Please read the answer again.

Comment: Oops! I never checked! :) Thanks for the help!